# Can we take out this term out of the integrand?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, conditional-probability, bayes-theorem

Suppose we have three (say continuous) variables $X$, $Y$ and $Z$. We know that may express the conditional probability $P[x\mid y]$, as follows:
\begin{equation}
P[x\mid y]=\int_{\mathbb{R}} P[x,z\mid y]dz
\end{equation}
or
\begin{equation}
P[x\mid y]=\int_{\mathbb{R}} P[x\mid z,y]P[z\mid y]dz
\end{equation}
Additionally, using the Bayes Theorem, we know that
\begin{equation}
P[x\mid y]=\int_{\mathbb{R}} P[x\mid z,y]\frac{P[y\mid z]P[z]}{P[y]}dz.
\end{equation}
Given the last equation, can we take $P[y]$ out of the integrand? In other words, can we express the last line instead as:
\begin{equation}
P[x\mid y]=\frac{1}{P[y]}\int_{\mathbb{R}} P[x\mid z,y]P[y\mid z]P[z]dz?
\end{equation}

Comment: Yes, $P[y]$ is the marginal distribution of $Y$. It does not depend on $z$ because the r.v. $Z$ has already been "integrated out" (that is the definition of a marginal distribution).

Comment: @Nirai Thank you that is what I suspected. I want to approve the answer, but for some reason it is not an option.